# Problems displaying special characters in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want my UILabel display text from SQLite database.
But it doesn't recognize new-line character "\n" - it just prints it on the screen like "Hello \n World".

This is how I get text value from the DB:

```
...
NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
myLabel.text = aDescription
...
```

Any suggestions?

**UPD**:
This question is not how to display multiple lines in UILabel. It is how to store and later encode newline character in SQLite.

Comment: How did you save the `\n` in the database in the first place. If you used a SQLite edit and just enter `\n` then it will be save literally as `\n` and not as the newline character you want it to be.

Comment: yes, I save it literally as \n. What can I use instead to save a newline character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you save `\n` and not the newline character.

If you use a SQLite editor you might want to copy past the text from a textedit with the newline character.

If you can't solve it on the in input side, which you should really do, then you need to replace the literal `\n` with the newline character:

```
NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
myLabel.text = [aDescription stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 1):

UILabel, by default, doesn't allow line breaks. If you want newlines to be effective, you have to set the labels' line number to a reasonably great number (and extend its `frame` property also):

```
label.numberOfLines = 5;
```

Or, as Matthias suggested:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

for allowing the label to display as many lines as needed.

Comment: The question is why is `\n` shown and not why it's not displayed on mutiple lines.

Comment: @rckoenes Question subject suggest that issue is "how to display" not "why it is stored".

Comment: The problem is not with multiple lines, but how to store and later encode a newline character

Comment: Yes the subject would suggest that, but if you read the question that it will become clear that its not.

Answer (score 0):

Your label height is not enough to print data in 2 lines ,increase height, and increase the number of line too
lbl.numberOfLines = 2;